# How to delete stripe link test account

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm running stripe in test mode and using payment elements. I activated stripe [link](https://link.co/), which allows users to save their credit card info. However, I can't figure out how to delete a **test** stripe link account. If you want to delete a Link account, you visit their website and delete it, but since my website is in test mode, the account's created aren't on link's website. Let me know if there is any way to delete it. I've tried deleting all the cookies and local/session storage, but the link account still stays.

Comment: I recommend reaching out to their support to get an answer on this

Comment: @Bob Stone did you get an answer from Stripe support Bob ?